# How do I access environment variables in config SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to access my environment variables inside a config file. Can I use this variable inside a config?

**For example**

```
// config/env/development.js
module.exports = {
  appUrl: 'http://MY_DEV_PLACE/',
}

//config/passport.js
var appUrl = appUrl || sails.config.appUrl  || 'localhost:1337'; //<-- sails is not defined
```

I also tried in `local.js`:

```
// config/local.js
module.exports = {
  gAPI: { secret: 'aaa'}
}

//config/passport.js
var appUrl = gAPI || sails.config.gAPI  || 'some pass'; //<-- sails is not defined
```

**EDIT:**

For **appURL** I'm using env like: `APP_URL=http://example.com/api sails lift`

For **password** I'm using:

```
var locals;

try {
    locals = require('./local');
} catch (e) {
    // not local so just ignore
}

module.exports.passport = {
    'GoogleAPI.Password': locals ? locals.gAPI.secret : ’some key'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the local.js file for environment variables. This file is discussed in-depth [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/configuration/the-local-js-file). This is pretty much the go to for storing environment variables in sails.

Important caveats: make sure this file is included in your .gitignore file lest you risk exposing important information to the world, this file will need to be configured for each environment (e.g. local, staging, production), you can access your environment variables via sails.config.variable_name, this file will take priority over the development.js and production.js file in the /env/ sub-directory.

Comment: I can't use local.js because I need to access a value inside a config.js (more specifically in passport.js) and local.js do not automatically load. Thats why my solution is manually load config/local.js `locals = require('./local');`

Answer (score 1):

I accessed the sails object from the routes.js like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(sails.config.frontendUrl)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **config/global.js**  add the following line....

```
   sails: true,
```

This makes `sails` instance global.

Comment: Is it the only choice? How can I use the env file for this?

Comment: I uncomment `sails: true` in global.js and still have `ReferenceError: sails is not defined` :-(

Comment: Do you know a good documentation that explains what should I put in env files? Because for me, my appURL should be added in env [production will have another appURL]

Comment: In Sailsdoc: `If you'd like to have some settings take effect only in certain environments, you can use the special environment-specific files and folders`. It does not appears to work